# How to type exactly in Excel sheet what I am typing in any other program using autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have to fill some information in some online forms as customer name, his address, his phone no and his father's name etc. I want that what I am filling in that online form should be automatically sent to an excel sheet without doing copy paste. Means I do not want to first copy this information and paste it to excel sheet.

I want to fill this information simultaneously at both the places i.e. Online form and excel sheet. As I type customer name WILL JACSON, it should automatically go in cell no a1 of an excel sheet without doing copy paste. Now I type his address as WARD NO 4 STREET NO 7.

Now this should go in cell no b1 of that excel sheet without doing copy paste. Now I type his phone no as 1234567890.

It should go automatically in cell no c1 of that excel sheet without doing copy paste. And so on. Is it possible?

Comment: what is the online form software? Can you export the data that you enter in your "online form" to CSV?

Comment: I work in a bank and there i have to fill forms in which i have fill the information related to the customer in  bank's own software. I want to export or send that information to an excel sheet..is it possible dear friends...

Comment: Please check if your banks' own software allows for export of information in such manner. If it has such facility then let us know what formats are allowed to be exported by that software. For CSV, plain text etc.,

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible.  The script below is initiated by control + shift + 1.

For a simple example, let's say you have an excel workbook with window title Book1 - Excel open and cursor in A1.  Your online form has five fields and is the active window with cursor ready to type in the first field.  Hit your control shift 1.  The hotkey will capture the next 300 characters you type for the first field until you hit tab.  When you hit tab, the information you typed will appear in cell A1 of excel.  Then right will be pressed to move the cursor to the next column in excel.  All the while, your online form is still the active window.  Then type your address field and hit tab again and so on.  No copy/paste necessary and the information will appear in both places as you type.

Make sure you have the latest version of autohotkey installed from ahkscript.org.  You may need to use ahk's Window Spy to get the control for excel or the exact window title. Use the window spy to make sure what it shows matches what I typed below.

You may need to adjust this script to fit your use case since your form could be more complex.  Keep in mind that if you type more characters than can fit in the form by accident, they will all be typed into excel.  Adjust wisely so you never run into that problem!

```
^+1::
Loop, 5
{
Input, inputVar, C IL300 V, %A_Tab%
controlsend, EXCEL71, %inputVar%{right}, Book1 - Excel
}
return
```